# Add UUIDs to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, uuid

How can I efficiently populate a column with UUIDs?

My guess was:

```
df['uuid'] = pd.Series([uuid.uuid1() for i in range(len(df))])
```

But I was wondering if it could be done using some kind built-in pandas method much more efficiently.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample dataframe?

Comment: There is no builtin method -- this is the fastest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
df['uuid'] = df.apply(lambda x: uuid.uuid1(), axis=1)
```